# Change Thread Priority of Async Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm hooked into the win32 low level mouse hook events and I would like to make that mouse click proc a higher thread priority so I can process mouse events while the UI thread is busy.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a long running process this should be run on its own thread independent of the UI thread. This should take care of your problem and restore the UIs responsiveness

Also, I think you're confusing terms, Threads are independent execution paths (a sort of sub process) bound to a main process (your running application). Clicks generate events which occur on the UI thread and are queued in the order they occurred. As far as I know, this order can not be changed (at least not easily).

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement async await to prevent background work from blocking the ui logic execution.